# WCF RIA Services 4004 error

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-ria-services

All works great in IIS Express, but when I debugging into local IIS, I've got error when trying use WCF in app (listed below), which browser shows, but VS don't.

```
[Window Title]
Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger

[Main Instruction]
An unhandled exception ('Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Invoke operation 'Login' failed. The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient`1.EndInvokeCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c__DisplayClass30`1.<InvokeOperation>b__2c(Object )     
') occurred in iexplore.exe [856].

The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. To debug this process, the Just-In-Time debugger must be run as an Administrator. Would you like to debug this process?

[V] View process details  [Yes, debug iexplore.exe] [No, cancel debugging]

[Expanded Information]
Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
User Name: Armanx64PC\Armanx64 [Elevated]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got solution. My head, it works so strange...

So, you need go to Control Panel - Programs and features - Turn features on or off, and there you must enable *ALL* WCF Services tree (check ASP.NET also, if you don't check it early).

Comment: This is ridiculous, why do those entries not get installed by default when installing IIS and ASP.Net, thanks Microsoft.

Comment: A lot of tasks, a more solutions. ASP.NET hosting isn't main WinServer task - see also about SQL Server, Active Directory and others.

Comment: 2 years after this is posted, I got the same error. Could you tell me which services exactly? I don't see any WCF services...